# SQL Error [42883] - function does not exist - Cannot call function from trigger

Tags: postgresql, trigger, functions, postgresql-10

I want to insert a new row to Table2 when Table 1 is inserted a row. I have created a function for that. However, when I try to create the trigger, it gives an error although function is created and I can see the function.

```
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function insertintoautoincrementexample() does not exist
```

Following are the details related to it. I tried to create the trigger with some text parameters but no luck.

```
//Table 1
CREATE TABLE myOriginalTable(
    companyName VARCHAR(15) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    location VARCHAR(30)    
);    

//Table 2    
CREATE TABLE autoincrementexample (
    entryid INT4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('autoincrementexample_entryid_seq'::regclass),
    companyname VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    location VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (companyname)
);

//Function    
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insertIntoAutoIncrementExample(companyname text,location text)

    returns void
    language plpgsql
    as $function$

    declare
    varaudseq bigint;

    begin
        varaudseq :=0;

    begin
        SELECT NEXTVAL(autoincrementexample) INTO varaudseq;
        INSERT INTO autoincrementexample(companyname,location)VALUES(companyName,location);
    COMMIT;
    END;
    END;
    $function$;

//Trigger
CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_original 
    AFTER INSERT ON myoriginaltable
    FOR EACH row
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE insertintoautoincrementexample();
```

Would appreciate any help regarding this.

Comment: Please tag your postgres version.

Comment: Hi @McNets version is 10.1-1. I cannot add as a tag since it does not exist.

Comment: is this relating to case sensitivity?

Comment: @EdgarAllanBayron Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that. No its not related.

Comment: Shouldn't trigger functions RETURNS TRIGGER?  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-trigger.html

Comment: @McNets Thanks. I am fairly new to SQL functions and triggers. I will look into that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/trigger-definition.html) says:

> The trigger function must be defined before the trigger itself can be
>   created. **The trigger function must be declared as a function taking
>   no arguments and returning type trigger**. (The trigger function
>   receives its input through a specially-passed TriggerData structure,
>   not in the form of ordinary function arguments.)

The function you have declared is:

```
insertIntoAutoIncrementExample(companyname text,location text) ... returns void
```

so it does not fit both in the return type and in the argument types.
A trigger function does not take arguments but can access the values inserted or changed in the row variables `NEW` and `OLD`. They get automatically defined in plpgsql, see [Trigger procedures](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html) in the plpgsql chapter for  details and examples.

Concerning the error message:

```
function insertintoautoincrementexample() does not exist
```

it means: this function name, with an empty list of arguments, does not exist.
The presence of parentheses around nothing is relevant, because in postgresql, functions always go with their argument types:
`foobar(int)` is not the same function than `foobar()`, or `foobar(int,int)` or `foobar(text)`.